# sql statement update substrings in all columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image]

There is a table with ampersand separated strings, and some of them contains special substrings PORT1&PORT2.. as you can see above. now I need a query that remove substrings exist in parameter list..

I need something that make the row: `'group1','PORT1&PORT2&PORT3&PORT4&aynthing&blabla&randomstr'` like this
`'PORT1&PORT4&aynthing&blabla&randomstr'`(search criteria PORT2,PORT3)

I need that query with db server independent(should work both mssql and MySQL)
I dont know it is possible or my imagination is incredible.

Comment: The foundation of your challenge is normalization. When you store multiple values in a single table intersection you are violating 1NF which causes untold amounts of pain for what would otherwise be a simple query.

Comment: Or course in your example it seems like a simple replace is all you need. Or is your parameter also a delimited list of values? In which case you will need to parse that into separate values.

Comment: @ yes exactly delimited list of values.. and yes maybe I can reconstruct database again but not have time now..

Comment: I think you should make time to refactor your db. If this table gets beyond a few thousand rows the query to search within each row will become prohibitive.  If I had this structure, I wouldn't even use a database.  Might as well use a flat file and load it all into memory, because that is what is going to happen when you query it.

Comment: You should also look into table valued parameters. sql server just isn't designed to handle delimited strings all over the place. In fact no DBMS that I am aware of is really any better at this kind of thing.

Comment: @SeanLange I am on redesign database I can you merge your first comment and this, as answer post I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foundation of your challenge is normalization. When you store multiple values in a single table intersection you are violating 1NF which causes untold amounts of pain for what would otherwise be a simple query.

You should also consider table valued parameters. It is a better way of passing multiple values into a procedure than a delimited string.